Solr complains about missing uniqueKey id, but it's there
I know there are many posts about a missing uniqueId but in my situation, it isn't missing.
The code I send to solr via curl is:
`http://solr.xxxxxxxxx.com:8983/solr/email/update/extract?commit=true&** *%26literal.archive_id_s%3D1690134
%26literal.attachment_id_s%3D2102500%26literal.base_name_s
%3D6658a301ea80b_28d248343289759_primal.mail.txt
%26literal.created_at_dt%3D2024-05-
30T12%3Dasxxxxxx%40xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com" -F 
"myfile=@/email_archive/attachments/2024/5/30/6658a301ea80b_28d2483432
89759_primal.mail.txt"`

I've bolded the id field in the code above.  I don't understand why I'm getting:
.   { "responseHeader":{ "status":400, "QTime":1}, "error":{ "metadata":[ "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException", "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"], "msg":"Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id", "code":400}}
I'd appreciate any suggestionss.
I've reviewed my schema.xml and see nothing of import.

There is no id field in the request you've included.

Just add &literal.id=12345 to that request.
Replace 12345 with a unique string or integer. Depending on which type of field your id is, in your Solr schema.xml.
This should be your request:
http://solr.xxxxxxxxx.com:8983/solr/email/update/extract? 
literal.id=12345&commit=true&literal.archive_id_s%3D1690134
%26literal.attachment_id_s%3D2102500%26literal.base_name_s
%3D6658a301ea80b_28d248343289759_primal.mail.txt
%26literal.created_at_dt%3D2024-05-
30T12%3Dasxxxxxx%40xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com" -F "myfile=@/email_archive/attachments/2024/5/30/6658a301ea80b_28d2483432
89759_primal.mail.txt"

In your example, you don't have any literal.id set for your document. Solr doesn't know what is your unique key there.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
